# Undefined offset: 1 when field is null

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a script to send mails but i am getting this error because my some fields are empty

my code is this

```
    $studentid = explode(',',$row['studentid']);
$Issue = explode(',',$row['Issue']);
$Ret = explode(',',$row['ret']);
$Consume = explode(',',$row['Consume']);
$Lost = explode(',',$row['Lost']);
$Damage = explode(',',$row['Damage']);
$Item = explode(',',$row['Item']);
$Description = explode(',',$row['Description']);
$Balance = explode(',',$row['Balance']);
$subject = "Inventory Detail";

// Create a line for each item/balance

    foreach($studentid as $key => $studentid){

$emailBody .= "<tr>";
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$serial999++.'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Item[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Description[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Issue[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Ret[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Consume[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Lost[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Damage[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Balance[$key].'</td>';
    }
    $emailBody .= "</tr>";
```

error is this

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mailtest\inventory.php on line 62

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mailtest\inventory.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mailtest\inventory.php on line 64

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mailtest\inventory.php on line 65
```

how to solve this problem

my full code is this

```
<?php
set_time_limit(120);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","inventory");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT   email, name, uid, GROUP_CONCAT(uid) as studentid, GROUP_CONCAT(item) as Item, GROUP_CONCAT(descr) as Description,  GROUP_CONCAT(issue) as Issue, GROUP_CONCAT(ret) as ret, GROUP_CONCAT(consume) as Consume, GROUP_CONCAT(lost) as Lost, GROUP_CONCAT(damage) as Damage, GROUP_CONCAT(Balance) as Balance FROM inventory_mail GROUP BY uid");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{
if($row['email'])
{
$to = $row['email'];
$emailBody = "";
$emailBody .= "<b>Dear</b>  ".$row['name'].",<br/><br/>";

    $emailBody .= "<table border='0' width='338' height='57'>";
    $emailBody .="<tr>";
    $emailBody .= "<td width='100'><b>Enroll No</b></td>";
    $emailBody .= "<td>: ".$row['uid']."</td>";
    $emailBody .="</tr>";
    $emailBody .= "</table>";
$today = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
$emailBody .= "<br/>Kindly find your Inventory details till <b>".$today."</b><br/><br/>";

$emailBody .="<table class=MsoTableGrid border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 style=border-collapse: collapse; border: medium none id=table1 align=center  width=800>
<tr>
<th>S.no</th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Issue</th>
<th>Return</th>
<th>Consume</th>
<th>Lost</th>
<th>Damage</th>
<th>Balance</th>
</tr>";
$serial999 = "1";
// explode the Pin/balances on the comma's
$studentid = explode(',',$row['studentid']);
$Issue = explode(',',$row['Issue']);
$Ret = explode(',',$row['ret']);
$Consume = explode(',',$row['Consume']);
$Lost = explode(',',$row['Lost']);
$Damage = explode(',',$row['Damage']);
$Item = explode(',',$row['Item']);
$Description = explode(',',$row['Description']);
$Balance = explode(',',$row['Balance']);
$subject = "Inventory Detail";

// Create a line for each item/balance

    foreach($studentid as $key => $studentid){

$emailBody .= "<tr>";
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$serial999++.'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Item[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Description[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Issue[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Ret[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Consume[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Lost[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Damage[$key].'</td>';
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$Balance[$key].'</td>';
    }
    $emailBody .= "</tr>";


$emailBody .= "</table>";

$emailBody .= "<br/>For More Details Login to http://lotus.edu.in/stafferp<br/><br/>Thanks,<br/>Lotus Institute of Management<br/>ERP System";

$emailBody= chunk_split(base64_encode($emailBody));
$headers = "From: Erp@lotus.edu.in\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: erp@lotus.edu.in\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: erp@lotus.edu.in\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";

      if(mail($to, $subject, $emailBody, $headers)) {
          echo 'Success:';
          echo '-----';
          echo $row['uid'];
          echo '-----';
          echo $row['name'];
          echo '-----';
          echo 'Email sent successfully!<br/><br/>';
      } else {
      }

}
else {
          echo 'Failure:';
          echo '-----';
          echo $row['uid'];
          echo '-----';
          echo $row['name'];
          echo '-----';
          echo 'Failure: Email was not sent!<br/><br/>';
      }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

i am getting this result

S.no    Item    Description Issue   Return  Consume Lost    Damage  Balance
1   A4_Rim          .   19      1           19
2   Neck_Strip  .   50      1           50
3   Pencil_cell .   1                   0
4   Whiteboard_Marker.  2                   1

instead of this

S.no    Item    Description Issue   Return  Consume Lost    Damage  Balance
1   A4_Rim          .   19                  19
2   Neck_Strip  .   50                  50
3   Pencil_cell .   1       1           0
4   Whiteboard_Marker.  2       1           1

it is changing order of values in consume column they should be at last two rows but it is setting them in first rows

Comment: `inventory.php on line 62` is ???

Comment: It looks like some of your `explode`'s are not returning more than 1 element into the array? It's possible some of your students don't have certain information associated with them? Either way you are missing some offset in one of those arrays..

Comment: which line you are specified..

Comment: These errors indicates `$Ret = explode(',',$row['ret']);
$Consume = explode(',',$row['Consume']);
$Lost = explode(',',$row['Lost']);
$Damage = explode(',',$row['Damage']);` these codes

Comment: that array return null or not??

Comment: first of all try `var_dump($row)` OR `print_r($row)`..

Comment: The way you're grouping the data it will not give you the desired result because it ANY of the values you're CONCATing is empty it will jump to the next record which will make your order all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code you have a bigger issue right now, which is the `GROUP_CONCAT`, if you have a `null` or `empty` entry anywhere it will give you a wrong amount and order of results.

For example, let's say the result should have been:

```
studentid   item
1           1
2           2
3           null
4           4
```

However `null` will be omitted from the result so you will actually get:

```
studentid   item
1           1
2           2
3           4
4
```

Following up, due to the last item not existing, `$Item` will not have the amount of index being read and not to mention `GROUP_CONCAT` can also scramble or have less entries and it will give you the error you have mentioned on your `foreach` as well as wrong data being displayed, same goes for the other variables you have.

[**Here is an DEMO of what your MySQL query does and why your results are not right.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21a36b/7)

In order to **prevent the error message** from happening you will have to verify the variable before you use it something like this:

```
// Create a line for each item/balance
foreach($studentid as $key => $studentid)
{
    //... rest of your code
    $emailBody .= '<td style="text-align:center;">' . (!isset($Item[$key]) ? '' : $Item[$key]) .'</td>';
    //... rest of your code
}
```

Basically we check if `$Item[$key]` is set if not print nothing avoiding the index errors from index not following the current index.

To fix the missing data to make the amount of index right you will have to change your MySQL query like this:

```
    SELECT email, name, uid, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(uid, '')) as studentid, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(item, '')) as Item, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(descr, '')) as Description,  
           GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(issue, '')) as Issue, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(ret, '')) as ret, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(consume, '')) as Consume, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(lost, '')) as Lost, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(damage, '')) as Damage, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(Balance, '')) as Balance 
      FROM inventory_mail 
  GROUP BY uid
```

By using `IFNULL(item, '')` if a given row is `null` it will set it as empty and will be present on the array as an empty row.

Comment: Read the top of my answer and u will know why its wrong, [I have also made a DEMO of your query to illustrate that.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21a36b/2)

Comment: it means it is not possible , now what should i do to complete this

Comment: @user3210029 see the update on my question on how you can change your MySQL query which might fix it. If you are 100% sure one of the columns are not going to be null you can remove the check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for variables

```
     if (isset($var[index])) {
         "do something here"
     }
```

first you check if variable exists or not, then only you can use it. Hope it helps.

like in your case

```
 if (isset($row['studentid'])) {
       $studentid = explode(',',$row['studentid']);
  }
 else{
      $studentid = NULL;
  }
```

Comment: these fields have no data in mysql they are null , can u show me my modified code

Comment: Same problem no success

Comment: you cannot use array value if its index is not available so you will have to apply checks when using indexes too